# How to read data from QTableWidget?

Tags: qt

The following is my piece of code:

```
QString fileName = appData + GROUND_DATALOG_DIR + "AISTABLE";
fileName = fileName + d_local.toString("_yyyy-MM-dd") + t_local.toString("_HH-mm-ss") + ".csv";
f_out = fopen(fileName.toAscii().data(), "wb+");
if (f_out == NULL) {
    return;
}

QString headerString = "MMSI, Vessel_Name, Longitude, Latitude , Type, Navigation, SOG, COG, True_Heading, IMO, Call_Sign, Ship_Type\r\n";

for(int row = 0;row <ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1; row++)
{
    for(int column = 0;column< ui->tableWidget->columnCount()-1 ;column++)
    {
        headerString += ui->tableWidget->item(100,5)->text() +",";
    }
    headerString += "\r\n";
}
fprintf(f_out,"%s",headerString.toAscii().data());
fflush(f_out);
fclose(f_out);
```

When I execute the program with item row and column value less than 100, I am getting output. But if the value exceeds 100 then I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x5463d72c in file.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is:

```
    headerString += ui->tableWidget->item(100,5)->text() +",";
```

You are asking for an item in row 100. So if there is no row 100, item() returns a nullptr. And that is giving you the error, I guess.

Maybe you wanted:

```
    headerString += ui->tableWidget->item(row,column)->text() +",";
```

Comment: I tried the above one. But again I got the same error.

Comment: I have created the Tablewidget using Qt designer with row=300 and column=12. I am able to write data to it. But i am getting error when i execute the above code.

Comment: Could you make the ode snipped a minimal compilable example? Did you try to debug it? Is the line I suspected giving you the error?

Comment: Yes. When I comment the above line (headerString += ui->tableWidget->item(row,column)->text() +",";) and execute, I will get the output.

Comment: Did you call setItem() for all your rows and columns? Otherwise I think you just create the table of the size you want, but there are still no items in it,

Comment: Thank you. I was doing the setItem() in another method. Now i corrected it and its working  fine.